# Apache Spark: Exception in thread "main" java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 0:

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have been working with apache spark(scala) and building the packages with sbt. I am able to build the package, but I keep getting a `Exception in thread "main" java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 0:` when I do a

```
./bin/spark-submit \  "/Users/Desktop/tranasactions/target/transaction_2.10-1.0.jar" --help
```

and I don't understand why that is the case.

Here is my code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object creditFraud {

def main(args: Array[String]) {

 val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Transaction")
 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

 val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc,"Users/grantherman/Desktop/transactionFile.csv")


println("GRAPHX: Number of vertices " + graph.vertices.count)
println("GRAPHX: Number of edges " + graph.edges.count)
    }
  }
```

Here is the .sbt file:

```
name := "Transaction"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.1" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "1.3.1" % "provided"


resolvers ++= Seq(
"Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/",
"Spray Repository" at "http://repo.spray.cc/")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are enter the command in a single line, please remove "\", so it will looks like:

```
./bin/spark-submit "/Users/Desktop/tranasactions/target/transaction_2.10-1.0.jar" --help
```

The "\" is the Bash escape character. If you trying to enter a long command, you can split your command into few lines, like:

```
./bin/spark-submit \ 
"/Users/Desktop/tranasactions/target/transaction_2.10-1.0.jar" --help
```

**Update**: 
My previous answer is only focus on "java.net.URISyntaxException".

In order to run the spark-submit, you can refer to its documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/submitting-applications.html

For your case, you can execute your jar file in below commands (assumed that your class name is **org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi**):

```
./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi "/Users/Desktop/tranasactions/target/transaction_2.10-1.0.jar"
```

OR split it to multiple lines:

```
./bin/spark-submit \ 
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
"/Users/Desktop/tranasactions/target/transaction_2.10-1.0.jar"
```

You can also specified the number of cores that you wish to run (let's say 4 cores):

```
./bin/spark-submit \ 
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--master local[4] \
"/Users/Desktop/tranasactions/target/transaction_2.10-1.0.jar"
```

If you are unsure that your jar file is working fine, I will suggest you to play around with the spark-examples-[version].jar first before get started.

Comment: So I got rid of that and I get keep getting that it can't read the main class. Do I need to add the parmeters class -- "className" and master --local[4]?

Comment: The original answer is only focus on your main error "java.net.URISyntaxException". I have updated my answer which should allow you to successfully execute the spark-submit.