# How to convert map to dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-sql

m is a map as following:

```
scala> m
res119: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Any,Any] = Map(A-> 0.11164610291904906, B-> 0.11856755943424617, C -> 0.1023171832681312)
```

I want to get:

```
name  score
A  0.11164610291904906
B  0.11856755943424617
C  0.1023171832681312
```

How to get the final dataframe?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First covert it to a `Seq`, then you can use the `toDF()` function.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val m = Map("A"-> 0.11164610291904906, "B"-> 0.11856755943424617, "C" -> 0.1023171832681312)
val df = m.toSeq.toDF("name", "score")
df.show
```

Will give you:

```
+----+-------------------+
|name|              score|
+----+-------------------+
|   A|0.11164610291904906|
|   B|0.11856755943424617|
|   C| 0.1023171832681312|
+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any

Comment: @garyyong your map is of type `Map[Any,Any]`. Change it to `Map[String,Double]` or whatever type you are using.

Comment: giving error- java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path

Comment: @parneetisood: You seem to have some unrelated issue. Maybe this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078482/apache-spark-exception-in-thread-main-java-net-urisyntaxexception-illegal-ch

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol toDF

Comment: @DachuanZhao: You need to use `import spark.implicits._`, see the full code in the answer.

Comment: error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]

Comment: @DachuanZhao: this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704831/value-todf-is-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark-rdd-rdd