# Convert scala map to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to stream twitter data using Apache Spark and I want to save it as `csv file` into HDFS. I understand that I have to convert it to a dataframe but I am not able to do so.

Here is my full code:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils
//import com.google.gson.Gson
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SparkSession}
//import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
//import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import sentimentAnalysis.sentimentScore

case class twitterCaseClass (userID: String = "", user: String = "", createdAt: String = "", text: String = "", sentimentType: String = "")

object twitterStream {

  //private val gson = new Gson()

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    //Twitter API
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", "#######")
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", "#######")
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", "#######")
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", "#######")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("twitterStream").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    val sc: SparkContext = spark.sparkContext
    val streamContext = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
    import spark.implicits._

    val filters = Array("Singapore")
    val filtered = TwitterUtils.createStream(streamContext, None, filters)
    val englishTweets = filtered.filter(_.getLang() == "en")

    englishTweets.print()

    val tweets = englishTweets.map{ col => {
          (
            "userID" -> col.getId,
            "user" -> col.getUser.getScreenName,
            "createdAt" -> col.getCreatedAt.toInstant.toString,
            "text" -> col.getText.toLowerCase.split(" ").filter(_.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$")).fold("")((a, b) => a + " " + b).trim,
            "sentimentType" -> sentimentScore(col.getText).toString
          )
        }
    }



    //val tweets = englishTweets.map(gson.toJson(_))

    //tweets.saveAsTextFiles("hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/sparkApp/test/")


    streamContext.start()
    streamContext.awaitTermination()

  }
}
```

I am not sure where did I possibly went wrong. There is another way to go about which is using `case class`. Is there a good example I can follow?

**Update**
The result of the Map function which is save into HDFS is like this:
`((userID,1345940003533312000),(user,rei_yang),(createdAt,2021-01-04T03:47:57Z),(text,just posted a photo singapore),(sentimentType,NEUTRAL))`

Is there a way to code it to a dataframe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert map to dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317098/how-to-convert-map-to-dataframe)

Comment: If you're using Structured Streaming, you'd already have a Dataframe that could be saved. Where's the map come from, or why are you mapping into a Map object?

Comment: In a way yes, however, it gives me an error ```cannot resolve symbol toDF()``` @mck

Comment: @OoIJac did you `import spark.implicits._`?

Comment: yes i did import, i have this issue for quite awhile thus i could not convert map to dataframe @mck

Comment: show the whole code please ...

Comment: added the whole code @UninformedUser

Comment: ehm how old is the Twitter Spark API? Isn't this still Spark 1.6? Which version do you use from where?

Comment: I use Spark 3? I am doing it in IntelliJ IDEA @UninformedUser

Comment: wel,, yeah - but the Twitter stuff is **not** part of official Spark - you're definitely suing some 3rd party API for it. This is most likely based on an older Spark version - so which API did you add for the Twitter stuff?

Comment: i think its the dependency ```"org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "2.4.0"``` @UninformedUser. If thats the case, is there any other legitimate API  i can follow?

Comment: given that it's a `DStream` you have to follow this way I think, i.e. iterate each `RDD` in the stream, convert it to `DataFrame`, then save it: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations

Comment: oh yes that work. Thank you! @UninformedUser

Comment: Hi @UninformedUser, each RDD is converted into a dataframe. Howver, How do i compile each RDD into a single dataframe?